# JQUERY Get value from <span> on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, alert, html

The problem is not that difficult, I just can't get my head around it (noob at Jquery). The problem all comes down to when clicking a `<span>` getting it`s text and print it;

```
$('span').click(function(){
var t= ???;
    alert(t);
});
```

How can i get it's text??? 
NOTE: Each span does not have an id or class, any span clicked must output a message.
Each span is generated dinamic via PHP and I need it's value.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
$('span').click(function(){
    var t = $(this).text();
    alert(t);
});
```

[**See a demo at jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/tpL4M/1/).

Comment: You're welcome.  Note that the other two had the same answer just a few seconds after mine.

Answer (score 4):

```
$('span').click(function(){
    var t= $(this).text();
    alert(t);
});
```

See [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/).

Answer (score 3):

use .text() ([http://docs.jquery.com/Text()](http://docs.jquery.com/Text%28%29))

```
$('span').click(function(){
        alert($(this).text());
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the span id without click

```
id = $("span.ClassName").attr('id');
```